# Cancellation of surface integrals (involving Maxwell's equation)

Tags: maxwell-equations, integration, magnetostatics

In our physics class today, we wanted to derive ${curl}(\bar B) =\mu_0 \bar j $ from the Maxwell equation $$\oint_C \bar B(\bar r).d\bar l = I_{net}\mu_0$$

We did this using Stokes theorem, and in the last step we used the step:

$$\iint_S {curl}(\bar B).\bar n dA = \iint_S \mu_0\bar{j}.\bar n dA \Rightarrow {curl}(\bar B) = \mu_0\bar j$$

I'm quite convinced this cancellation is not mathematically legit, but maybe I'm overseeing a physical argument or something like that so I can justify this step anyway?

Comment: What "cancellation"? You mean "cancelling" the integrations?

Comment: Yes (see title)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No physics, just a purely mathematical argument. 
Stokes's theorem: $\oint_{C} {\vec{v}}\cdot d{\vec l} = \int\int_{S} curl\vec{v} \cdot \vec{dS}$, where $\vec v$ is any differentiable vector field and $C$ any simple (piecewise) smooth loop that bounds a simple smooth (etc.) surface $S$. So if Maxwell's equation is written as $\oint_{C} {\vec{B}}\cdot d{\vec l} = \int\int_{S} \mu_0\vec{J} \cdot \vec{dS}$ then one has $ \int\int_{S} curl\vec{B} \cdot \vec{dS} = \int\int_{S} \mu_0\vec{J} \cdot \vec{dS}$ for *any* such surface $S$, even for an infinitesimally small one. Take limit and you get *pointwise* the differential form $curl\vec{B}= \mu_0 \vec{J}$ of Maxwell's equation.

Answer (score 0):

For a vector, you can't use cancellation directly. If $\vec{b}\dot{}\vec{a}=\vec{c}\dot{}\vec{a}$, you just obtain $bcos<\vec{a},\vec{b}>=ccos<\vec{a},\vec{c}>$ or $b_n=c_n$, and in the special case of $<\vec{a},\vec{b}>=<\vec{a},\vec{c}>$ you can get $\vec{b}=\vec{c}$.